# htaccess empty referer deny "google bot"

Tags: htaccess, web-crawlers, googlebot, 403-forbidden

1. I put this rule into htaccess file to deny empty referers which is returning 403

   ```
   SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^$" bad_user  
   Deny from env=bad_user
   ```

   I can see the log, it's denying also Googlebot which is acting as empty referrer also. Is there a way to modify the rule to allow access for Googlebot and deny all the rest empty referrers?
2. I have blocked one referrer `www.example.com` using

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example\.com [NC]  
   RewriteRule .* - [F]
   ```

   It's working well, returning 403, but what if he is referring from  `example.com/another_page`?

   So I did this:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example\.com [NC,OR]  
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example/another_page\.com/ 
   RewriteRule .* - [F]
   ```

   Is it correct?
3. How can I block this user agent: `Mozilla/5.0/Firefox/42.0 - nbertaupete95(at)gmail.com`?
   What should the rule look like?
   Will this one work?

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^nbertaupete95(at)gmail.com [NC]  
   RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
   ```

Comment: It is not the referrer which is causing the 403, rather it is the server. A 403 Indicates that the server understands the request, but refuses to authorize the request. I suggest referencing the question asked in Stack overflow here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses

Comment: yes..but the server is telling this way that the referrer has no permission to access the website, right?

Comment: Once thing is for certain (or at least in most cases), which is that we certainly would not want to deny the GoogleBot. Does your site have a robots.txt file?

Comment: yes it does..thats why Im asking how to refuse an empty referrer without blocking the googlebot.

Comment: If your referrer is https & you are http, referrer data is lost in most cases

Comment: in log, "protocol field" is saying HTTP/1.1 for the empty referrer

Comment: isnt there a rule to block empty referrers except google bot?

Comment: For clarity, Will you send an example web server log (redact IP info)?

Comment: looks like this - IP:141.101.76.103   URL: /   SIZE:28206 (bytes)    STATUS:200   METHOD:GET   PROTOCOL:HTTP/1.1  REFERRING URL:"empty field"   USER AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko     , i know this is bad one and i want to block him, cant deny ip because he is using different ips and he is behind the cloudfalre, cant find out his orginal ip thats why im trying to solve this problem some other way.

Comment: Why are you trying to deny access to his with no referrer?  In addition to search engine spiders not using referrers, visitors that type in your URL or visit from an email won't have them.  Some users install browser plugins to disable referrers.   The referrer is so often empty that you could be causing problems for 10% or more of your legitimate visitors.

Comment: well i will tell you right away why...he is scraping and cloning my website..and somehow is referring from the clone he made to my website urls which doesnt even exist, i really dont know what kind of black hat cloning cloaking technique he is using but its working very well for him...so thats why i want to block him..ip deny wont work as i have already said...and he is referring as an empty referrer...ok i will put it this way...what rule i can use to block this user agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Comment: i ve tried this one but not working :    SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko" bad_user  this user agent is asigned to him in the log file i just want a rule to block this user agent.

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller is correct about direct visits. Have you checked to see what Country of origin the undesired visits are coming from? In the event that you were using wordpress, you could simply install wordfence and block all countries except for your own. What metrics are you using that make you think that he is somehow obtaining some advantage with your content? Google looks at things such as document inception date, and I can assure you that any website that is copying your content will be treated as such & will have no longevity in the long haul.

Comment: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko` - You should not block this user-agent. This is a common user-agent used by IE11 - so if you block this you will likely block many legitimate users! You stated a very different user-agent in your question?

Answer (score 1):

As you have found (and warned against in comments), you should not try to block requests that contain an empty `Referer` header. Google (and most bots) and many legitimate users will not send the HTTP `Referer` header (at least at some point), so this will just cause you problems.

To answer the two remaining queries in your question...

> 2. I have blocked one referrer `www.example.com` using
>
>    ```
>    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example\.com [NC]  
>    RewriteRule .* - [F]
>    ```
>
>    It's working well, returning 403, but what if he is referring from  `example.com/another_page`?

You don't need to change anything to your existing directive(s). The first `RewriteCond` directive already blocks any referer that simply *contains* `example.com`. Note that `example\.com` is a regex (*regular expression*) (which is why the dot is backslash escaped). Without any *anchors*, the pattern is naturally matched anywhere inside the `HTTP_REFERER`.

(However, the *pattern* in your additional directive `example/another_page\.com/` is a bit *mashed* anyway, so would never match as intended. That wouldn't have mattered, since it will have matched the first *condition* anyway.)

> 3. How can I block this user agent: `Mozilla/5.0/Firefox/42.0 - nbertaupete95(at)gmail.com`? What should the rule look like? Will this one work?
>
>    ```
>    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^nbertaupete95(at)gmail.com [NC]
>    RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
>    ```

No, this would not work, the regex is not correct. You have introduced a start of string *anchor* (`^`) on the regex, so it will only match user-agents that *start* "nbertaupete95...". In the stated user-agent string, this substring is *contained within* it.

Also, parentheses (`(` and `)`) are special meta characters in regex - they are used for *alternation* and to capture subpatterns. To match a literal parenthesis, these must be backslash-escaped, eg. `\(`.

So, your example should read something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} nbertaupete95\(at\)gmail\.com
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

The `L` flag is not required when using `F` (it is implied). The `NC` flag on the `_CondPattern_` is also unnecessary, unless this user-agent really does have case variation? Also, dots must be escaped to match a literal dot, as you did in your earlier directives.

In the stated user-agent, the "email address" occurs at the end of the user-agent. If this is the case, then you can add an end-of-string *anchor* (`$`) to the regex, for example: `nbertaupete95\(at\)gmail\.com$`.